# What is the best way to invest in US stocks from India?

Tags: india, starting-out-investing, start-up, nasdaq

Being an Indian citizen, I would like to trade in US stock markets (i.e. in NASDAQ and NYSE)

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite a few stock broker in India offer to trade in US markets via tie-up brokers in US. As an Indian citizen, there are limits as to how much FX you can buy, generally very large, should be an issue. The profits will be taxed in US as well as India [you can claim relief under DTAA]

Comment: do you advice to invest in US stock exchange ? do you have any reference brokers that provides such ? or can we directly contact to any US stock brokers ?

Comment: @MokshShah On this forum specific product recommendation is avoided. Most leading brokers like Kotak Securities, ICICI Direct provide the facilities. Whether to invest or not depends on specific goals and risk appetite. If you are new recommendation would be first to deal with Local securities, then International.